# Looking to use Partitions to Compare Two Different Columns on Previous Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am using SQL Developer and am trying to find a way to create a renewal indicator. I have a table with policy numbers, effective dates, and expiration dates. If a certain policy has a new effective date the same as the expiration date of the previous row, then it should get a "1" because it renewed. If there is no new effective date, the policy did not renew. In my example below policies 12345 and 12389 should get a "1" and policy 12367 should get a "0". How do I do this? Somehow using PARTITION BY, ROWS PRECEDING, etc?

```
    POLICY_NUMBER    EFFECTIVE_DATE     EXPIRATION_DATE
       12345           20140120            20140720
       12345           20140720            20150120
       12367           20140122            20140722
       12389           20140122            20140722
       12389           20140722            20150122
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You are right, You need to use partition by and order by. Following query will work for you :

```
SELECT A.POLICY_NUMBER , 
CASE WHEN A.EXPIRATION_DATE = B.EFFECTIVE_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ISRENEW
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY POLICY_NUMBER ORDER BY POLICY_NUMBER) AS NUM1 , 
POLICY_NUMBER , EFFECTIVE_DATE , EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM POLICYTABLE AS A
) AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY POLICY_NUMBER ORDER BY POLICY_NUMBER) AS NUM1 , 
POLICY_NUMBER , EFFECTIVE_DATE , EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM POLICYTABLE AS A
) AS B ON A.NUM1 = B.NUM1 - 1 AND A.POLICY_NUMBER = B.POLICY_NUMBER
WHERE A.NUM1 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this type of logic in one of our application.